# Remove Mysterious 20px Margins - Bootstrap 3.3.4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've picked my code apart, and there's an annoying little margin issue going on that I'm stumped with. I created a Bootstrap v3.3.4 website, but on the navbar and images, there's a 20px-ish margin that either looks like a gutter or overhang. I've tried resetting the CSS margins and padding by applying this class to rows

```
.row.no-gutters {
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
}
.row.no-gutters > [class^="col-"],
.row.no-gutters > [class*=" col-"] {
     padding-left: 0;
     padding-right: 0;
}
```

and including this in my stylesheet

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   font: inherit;
   vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

But I'm having no luck getting rid of these margins. I am working from an older version of the website, which has different bugs, which I'm trying to repair...somehow, though the stylesheets are *almost* identical, the margins on the newer version are funky. Here is an image of the trouble spots

What I want the navbar to look like:

[image: What I want the navbar to look like:]

What the navbar currently looks like:

[image: What the navbar currently looks like:]

What I want the sidebar to look like:

[image: What I want the sidebar to look like:]

What the sidebar currently looks like:

[image: What the sidebar currently looks like:]

See my code and demo it here on Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/IPVa7Y86Grv1SSj9hWBt?p=preview

You'll notice a small margin about 20px on the left and right side of the sidebar image, and around the placeholder boxes in the footer. I've noticed that the margins remain with both images and text. There is also a 20px-ish margin overhang between the .wrapper and navbar, but it's not possible to see that within Plunker. Though I did try to replicate it.

Comment: What browser are you using? I cannot reproduce this using chrome.

Comment: I am using the most modern version of Chrome, Windows 7 computer.

Comment: Sorry, still cannot reproduce, maybe it could be a user-script / extension that you've installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Joansy** Hi there again.

**Manoj Kumar** is right, about the use of how to use Bootstrap `container`and `row`.

This is what's giving you a problem here.

Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ko6n162/)**.
I have quickly gone through making some changes to resolve your issues here with your code.
Have a look between the two codes to see the difference.
The scroll bar at the bottom is now gone too.

**Updated Fiddle for no padding on images.**

Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ko6n162/2/)** to see if this is how you want the images to be displayed.

Comment: AngularJR This solves the issue with the navbar overhanging margin. I'm still working on trying to remove the margin from around the images (the one on the top of the sidebar, and the three above the footer).

Comment: Hi, It actually cleared up everything from the nav down to and including the footer. What issue do you want to fix re a image? How do you want the images to look/display here?

Comment: The images have an automatic "gutter" of about 15-20px on the left and right. I've been able in the past to make a website where there are no gutters, but I can't see in my code where it's causing this. Above, I've included one screenshot of the sidebar (with a yellow flower image). You can see that in the 2nd screenshot, there is a blue bar on the right padding, then a small white space. This is bad. In the 1st screenshot, there is no padding, just the small white space. I'm trying to get it to look like the 1st screenshot.

Comment: I also noticed you removed the .wrapper, which I have to keep. Basically, the only thing I added was a .container-fluid starting at the banners and ending after the footer. I also cleaned up some .rows which weren't needed. Thank you for your help, I think we're moving in the right direction.

Comment: **Joansy**, have a look at the new fiddle which has no padding on the images.  Please do not add the wrapper. I moved it down below the **nav**. It is just the `container`now.

Comment: AngularJR Thank you so much for your persistence! I This works. Not trying to be obstinate, but what is wrong with having the wrapper in that position? Is it for testing? Does it mess with the nav? Just curious.

Comment: Hey that is great that this is all working for you now.  No problem, when I said don't add the wrapper... I meant don't add another **container**   class at the top where you had it before. Ok to add the class `wrapper` to a existing div with the container class. What we are trying to prevent again is you using a `container`inside another  `container`.  You will find the container that I moved is now on line 407. It is actually a `container-fluid`class.  Hope this all helps.

Answer (score 1):

Joansy, you need to correct  your bad practice of the Twitter Bootstrap code. The below two items are causing the `mysterious margin` you are talking about

1. Never nest a container insider another container

[**From Docs**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

> Containers
>
> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and
>   house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in
>   your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container
>   is nestable.

2. Wrap the row inside a container to avoid the negative margins set on `row` to extend the element.

Comment: When I wrapped the div above the .side row inside a container, like so: <div class="container"><div class="row"></div></div> it actually added another 15px of white margin to the left side.

Comment: Can you make a Bootly/Plunker example of what you mean?

Comment: Checkout AngularJR's JSfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using .row class without his .col-* childrens. In bootstrap, a `<div class="row">` have a `margin: 0 -15px` to compensate the 15px padding of the cols. You need to add cols if you need to use a row. If you don't need, simply remove the class .row of the parent div.

Two solutions:

## 1st

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12>
   YOUR NAVBAR CONTENT
  </div>
 </div>
```

## 2nd

```
 <div class="container wrapper">
  <!-- remove here the row class -->
        <header ....>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. The 1st, no change occurred. The 2nd, it made header banner image disappear (only white background remains).